# Should I have removed `(shell . t)` to clear an ob-shell initialization error?

Tags: init-file, shell

First post. I'd like to confirmation whether I sucessfully troubleshooted an install of Emacs, and, if I didn't, direction on where and how to proceed.

My setup:

- Emacs 24.5
- Macbook Pro Core Duo (mid-2010)
- OSX El Cap (10.11.4)

I recently installed Emacs along with Kierian Healy's [https://kieranhealy.org/resources/emacs-starter-kit/](social science starter kit). When I first launched Emacs after the installation I received an error (below) that as far as I could tell, didn't prevent anything from working—although, given that I'm new to Emacs one can never be sure.

Once installed, I received the follwing error message at launch:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading     
`/Users/lmp/.emacs.d/init.el':

File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, ob-shell

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I launched Emacs from the terminal into debug mode but couldn't for the life of me figure out the backtrace. So I commented out sections of my init.el file until I found the problem line of code:

```
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "starter-kit.org" dotfiles-dir))
```

So I opened the starter-kit.org file and do the same which leads me to the following code

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
'org-babel-load-languages
'((emacs-lisp . t)
(shell . t)))
```

After searching the org-mode website and a few forums, I tried the following that cleared the error:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
'org-babel-load-languages
'((emacs-lisp . t)))
```

It's my understanding that the `. t` part of the code is a true/false signifier. But whether removing it from the file was wise or foolish, is what I want to know. Or, to state my question in the clearest of terms:

1. Did I successfully fix the problem? If not, why not?
2. Is there anything I should have done instead, or should do in addition to removing the `(shell . t)`?

Answer (score 7):

Did you successfully fix the problem? Sure! `ob-shell` was flipping out and you stopped loading it. That is, in some sense, a fix!

That said: the chunk of code you found and commented out controls which languages are loaded by [org babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/), which is a pretty powerful function within org. If you've got any interest in using/evaluating shell code blocks, you'll want to fix the error you got a different way. You're right -- `. t` associates truth with a value. In this case, it indicates that org should load the shell backend for org source blocks.

All this said: if you want the shell backend running, there isn't reeeeeally enough information in your original post to diagnose what's wrong with it. I can tell you my config file doesn't have `(shell . t)`, but rather `(sh . t)`. One thing to double-check is that you're using a version of Org Mode greater than 8, which you can do with `M-x org-version`. Beyond that, I've very little to suggest at time of writing.

So! Do you want to use shell source blocks? If yes: more problem solving ahead! If no: you fixed it!

Comment: Thank you, @Gastove 

I'm switching to Emacs so that I can write academic papers in org-mode with R code for statistics: so yes, I'll need the shell as far as I can tell. I'll definitely review the babel and shell documentation with care in the coming days. 

Quick follow up: I tried replacing `(shell . t)` with `(sh . t)` and it too clears the error. Are those two functionally the same thing?

Comment: Honestly: I would have hoped `(shell . t)` would work; I know `(sh . t)` also works, so I suggested it, but I know the loader is a little finicky.

Comment: I can confirm that replacing `(shell . t)` by `(sh . t)` in the file `~/.emacs.d/starter-kit-org.org` works. At least on my FreeBSD installation.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem.  I got my fresh new Emacs 25.3 with a built-in `org-mode` of version 8.2.10.  When I started Emacs with my old init file, I got the exactly same thing.

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, ob-shell
```

I googled the error message and found this question.  Then I changed `(shell . t)` to `(sh . t)`.  It seemed to resolve the error message.

However, some days later, when I tried to really use `org-mode`, I found the built-in version lacking some feature and updated it to 9.1.4.  Then I encountered the following error when reallying executing something in `org-mode`.

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: org-babel-get-header
```

Then I changed `(sh . t)` back to `(shell . t)` and resolved the problem.

It seemed to me that the name of `ob-sh` was changed from `ob-sh` to `ob-shell` somewhere between version 8.2.10 and 9.1.4.